# Haskell "data" equivalent in Object Oriented Language

Tags: c#, haskell

In Haskell you can easily define a complex structure in a few lines. A small example being:

```
data A = B Float
       | C Int
       | D [D]

data D = E [A]
       | F Int
```

To convert this to an object oriented language, would you have to create a class for `A-F` then use inheritance to define this same structure? Or is there some other short hand?

I have an assignment which the data types are specified in Haskell, and I (mistakenly) chose C# but it is too late to go back now.

Comment: I don't know Haskell. Does this mean that A is an object containing a float, an int, and... B?  And D contains an instance of A and an int? (What is B? Another float, or the same float?) I look forward to the answer because I'll probably learn something.

Comment: @ScottHannen `A` is an object containing exactly one of a `Float`, an `Int`, or a list of `B`s. `D` is an object containing exactly one of a list of `A`s or an `Int`. The `B` type is not yet defined in this snippet (possibly McAngus meant `data B = ...` instead of `data D = ...`?).

Comment: I don't think that can be very well represented in C#. A class property can be only one thing - a single property can't represent the possibility of a float or an int or another type. A property could be of type 'object` in which case you could put anything in it, but then it has no specific type at all. It could also be anything else (or null.) Am I understanding that right? You could write something with multiple properties but then you'd be working against the language.

Comment: You can use generics for that `class A<T> where T : Int32, Int64`

Comment: @RoyalBg Generic constraints in C# are additive, something cannot be both a float and an int.

Comment: The so-called "visitor pattern" (AKA Church encoding) is the closest OOP concept to algebraic data types. I'd recommend you have a look at that.

Comment: @chi I think that's what McAngus was referring to with "create a class [...] then use inheritance". If not, then that is what I would suggest and do in the general case.  For McAngus, are you intending to restrict to data types where constructors only have one component, or do you want the general case?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement any ADT in C# that has at least one constructor. I do not know of any implementation for `data Void`. The products are easy, as these are simply classes or structs, but sums are not native to the language and so you have to do some extra work.

```
data Example a =
    Foo { foo :: a }
  | Bar { bar :: a, qux :: Int }
```

This is the example I will implement using the usual *tagged union*. You can define a union like in C but this is unusual in C#. Instead I will use an extra indirection, but the principle is the same. From the example I give it should be clear how to extrapolate to any ADT.

```
// Sealed because we don't want subtypes of our ADT.
public sealed class Example<A>
{
  // A class for each constructor.
  // Sealed because we cannot allow subtypes to be defined and used.
  public sealed class Foo
  {
    public readonly A foo;
    public Foo(A foo) { this.foo = foo; }
  }

  // A class for each constructor.
  // Sealed because we cannot allow subtypes to be defined and used.
  public sealed class Bar
  {
    public readonly A bar;
    public readonly int qux;
    public Bar(A bar, int qux) { this.bar = bar; this.qux = qux; }
  }

  // An enum of constructors.
  // Private because this is an implementation detail.
  private enum Tag : byte
  {
    Foo,
    Bar
  }

  // Store the constructor used.
  // Private because this is an implementation detail.
  private readonly Tag TheTag;

  // Store the term object.
  // Private because we will define safe case analysis to access
  // this value later.
  private readonly object Term;

  // The only constructor.
  // Private because we are going to define proper ways to
  // construct Example`1 later.
  private Example(Tag tag, object term)
  {
    TheTag = tag;
    Term = term;
  }

  // Case analysis. This is how you get the value back out.
  // This is like case/of or the functions "maybe", "either", etc.
  public B Cases<B>(Func<Foo,B> caseFoo, Func<Bar,B> caseBar)
  {
    // Because we defined an enum we can use an efficient switch
    // statement to jump directly to the correct branch.
    switch (TheTag)
    {
      // These casts are guaranteed to be safe because of the
      // functions we define to construct Example`1's.
      case Tag.Foo: return caseFoo((Foo)Term);
      case Tag.Bar: return caseBar((Bar)Term);
      // C# does not check the exhaustiveness of the switch statement
      // so we have to throw something here unfortunately.
      default: throw new Exception("missing case!");
    }
  }

  // This constructs an Example`1 with the Foo constructor.
  public static Example<A> Create(Foo term)
  {
    return new Example<A>(Tag.Foo, term);
  }

  // This constructs an Example`1 with the Bar constructor.
  public static Example<A> Create(Bar term)
  {
    return new Example<A>(Tag.Bar, term);
  }

  // You can define whatever other conveniences you want!

}
```

When I implement an ADT in C# I am trying to come as close as I can to Haskell. If `Example<A>` was not sealed then subtypes could be defined, but this is not something you can do with ADTs in Haskell. If `Foo` or `Bar` were not sealed then subtypes could be defined, but Haskell does not feature subtyping a constructor.

C# has `null` and there is nothing that can be done about it, so I have to ignore that as a possibility. If you're working with certain ADTs such as `Maybe`, or any ADT with a zero-argument constructor then you can use a struct and avoid the `null` problem. I will example this later.

Constructing `Example<A>` should work like it does in Haskell. That is why the only publicly available ways to construct `Example<A>` is through `Create(Foo)` and `Create(Bar)`. You could refactor to use C# constructors for this, but actually in C# constructors are inconvenient because they do not benefit from type inference nor can they be typed as delegates. In fact, to infer the type parameter `A` you would define a second static class called `Example` and define two `Create` methods there, just as `Tuple.Create` is.

Case analysis should also work as it does in Haskell. Unlike `Nullable<T>`, for example, this solution is impossible to use incorrectly (barring reflection, which can ruin anything). This may cost performance and may cost readability sometimes but that can be a worthwhile tradeoff for correctness.

With constructors and case analysis taken care of we're done.

You will not get away with the brevity of Haskell's ADTs in C#. I recommend using code generation to overcome this problem. Also, if you do find time to make such a tool, please share!

Finally I offer an implementation for `Maybe<A>`. This implementation is special because unlike `Example<A>` it does not have any unwanted values (`Example<A>` unfortunately has the value `null`). You can achieve the same for any ADT which has a zero-argument constructor.

```
// A struct instead of a sealed class. This means instead of
// null we have the implicit empty constructor. The empty
// constructor initializes all fields to their default values
// which is determined by their type.
//
// The trick here is that default(Maybe<A>) = Maybe<A>.Nothing().
//
public struct Maybe<A>
{
  // Same as before.
  private enum Tag : byte
  {
    // Must be 0, because this is the default value of any enum.
    Nothing = 0,
    Just = 1
  }

  // By default is Nothing
  private readonly Tag TheTag;

  // Can use type A instead of object. Saves a cast.
  private readonly A Value;

  // Same as before.
  private Maybe(Tag theTag, A value)
  {
    TheTag = theTag;
    Value = value;
  }

  // Same as before.
  public B Cases<B>(Func<B> caseNothing, Func<A,B> caseJust)
  {
    switch (TheTag)
    {
      case Tag.Nothing: return caseNothing();
      case Tag.Just: return caseJust(Term);
      default: throw new Exception("missing case!");
    }
  }

  // Same as before.
  public static Maybe<A> Nothing()
  {
    return new Maybe<A>(Tag.Nothing, default(A));
  }

  // Same as before.
  public static Maybe<A> Just(A value)
  {
    return new Maybe<A>(Tag.Just, value);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

java equivalent of

```
data A = B Float
       | C Int
       | D [B]
```

can be written as such

```
interface A {};  // marker interface
class B implements A {
    final float value;
    B(float value) {this.value=value;}   // constructor
}
class C implements A {
    final int value;
    C(int value) {this.value=value;}     // constructor
}
class D implements A {
    final B[] values;
    D(B[] values) {this.values=values;}  // constructor
}
```

etc.

Comment: Is your intent that you would use `instanceof` and downcasting to work with these?  Otherwise your solution is incomplete.  Also, I suspect that this is the solution the OP had in mind and is wondering if there is an alternative.

Comment: You are correct, this is what I have been doing. The reason I am looking for an alternative is that the number of Haskell lines is a lot less than the number of C# or Java lines for the equivalent.

Comment: yes, `instanceof` checks will be like constructor pattern matching in Haskell.  Number of lines won't be comparable since Haskell has a very sophisticated type system.  I"m not sure about C# but C++ has a primitive Union type whereas  Java doesn't.

Comment: @karakfa C# allows to emulate unions from C++ with `StructLayout` attribute.